# How to integrate a Liquibase migration into my grails build?

Tags: grails, liquibase

I have a Liquibase migration that I manually run to load seed data from several CSV files into my database. I would like to run this migration each time I run `grails run-app`.

I think I have two questions in one:

1. How to I integrate the `migrate`
   command into my `grails run-app` ?
2. How do I clear the `DATABASECHANGELOG`
   to allow me to run the same
   migration over and over?

Or, is there a better way to load a lot of data into a DB from CSV files?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Question 1 - To integrate migrate command into run-app, you should listen for events thrown in run-app scripts.   This is explained [here](http://grails.org/doc/1.0.x/guide/4.%20The%20Command%20Line.html), and a more complete article is [here](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/java/library/j-grails08128.html?ca=drs-).

Question 2 - For clearing the database, perhaps you can write a migration that clears the db for you?  The way I do it is use a little script I wrote that just drops and creates a db.  It's for MySQL:

```
target(dropdb: "The description of the script goes here!") {
   def x = 'mysql -u root --password=XXXX -e "drop database yourdb; create database yourdb default character set utf8; " '.execute(); 
   x.waitFor()
    println "Exit Value ${x.exitValue()}"
}

setDefaultTarget(dropdb)
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use the [autobase plugin](http://grails.org/plugin/autobase). It will run your migrations when the application starts.

It has a script to convert from an xml changelog to a groovy one as well so you don't have to manually convert it.

Comment: Its Helpful to know that Autobase is a light Groovy wrapper around Liquibase that provides a slick DSL for changesets that is more flexible than an XML file :-)

Answer (score 1):

Question #2: If you have particular changeSets you want to run every time, there is an "alwaysRun" attribute you can set on the changeSet tag.

Answer (score 1):

For my money, it's easier to read the Liquibase Gant scripts and replicate what they do. They're simple and you'll have more insight into what's happening.